# Onto Function Equivalence

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I was given a function $f:A\rightarrow B$, and was asked to find the statements in answer choices that are equivalent to saying $f$ is onto. I am wondering, is there a way I can mechanically simplify the answer choices and see if they are equivalent to the definition of an onto function? How should I approach this kind of questions? Thanks.

The definition of onto function on the textbook is: $$\forall y\in B,  \exists x\in A, f(x) = y$$

And here are the answer choices:

1. $$\neg \exists x\in A, \forall y\in B \; f(x) \not= y$$
2. $$\forall y\in B, \exists x\in A, \exists w \in B \; f(x)=w \land y=w$$
3. $$\neg \exists y\in B, \forall x\in A\; f(x) \not= y$$
4. $$\forall y\in B, \exists x\in A \; f(x)=y$$
5. $$\forall x\in A, \exists y\in B \; f(x)=y$$

Comment: Define some simple functions you have encountered in your past. Polynomials, sines, cosines, piecewise functions etc. Drawing little pictures, whether not you have a formula for it, usually helps. Observe on these whether or not they are onto and examine these numbers 1-4. 

Checking these conditions on various functions will give you valuable insight.

Comment: Clearly, 4. is equivalent to (identical with) the posted definition.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. Just to make sure, sines and cosines functions can be considered as onto functions, right? And also, sorry that I forgot to remove choice 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $\neg\exists u\in U\colon P(u)$ is equivalent to $\forall u\in U\colon \neg P(u)$. Similarly $\neg \forall u\in U\colon P(u)$ is equivalent to $\exists u \in U\colon \neg P(u)$.
In other words you can "slide" a negation through a quantifier as long as you also "invert" the quantifier (from $\exists$ to $\forall$ and vice-versa).
Using this rule you can transform the third statement into the fourth (which happens to be your original definition) and the first into the fifth.

The second statement is like the fourth, except $f(x)=y$ is replaced by $\exists w\in B\colon f(x)=w\wedge y=w$.
Clearly the second of these implies the first (since $f(x)=w=y$ implies $f(x)=y$). As long as $f(x)$ and $y$ are elements of $B$ (which they are in this context), the converse also holds (since you can take $w$ to be $y$).

So we see that $1.\leftrightarrow 5.$ and $2.\leftrightarrow 3.\leftrightarrow 4$

Now you just need to convince yourself that 5. (and hence 1.) is true for *any* function, no matter if onto or not; hence it is not equivalent to the others.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it makes more sense now. So when I "apply the negation and invert the quantifier, do I "invert" all the quantifiers in the statement? For example, I only negated $f(x) = y$ in $\neg \exists y\in B, \forall x\in A\; f(x) \not= y$, but do I "invert" both quantifiers seen?

Comment: whenever you slide a negation past a quantifier, you "invert" the quantifier. So you would start with $\neg \exists y \in B \colon\forall x\in A\colon f(x)\neq y$, get to $\forall y\in B\colon\neg \forall x\in A\colon f(x)\neq y$, and finally have $\forall y\in B\colon\exists x\in A\colon \neg f(x)\neq y$ which is of course equivalent to $\forall y\in B\colon\exists x\in A\colon f(x)=y$.
Of course you can also do both steps at once; move the negation through both quantifiers and "invert" them both.

Comment: Fantastic, thank you!